# how to get number of records from last 30 days using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am fetching a data for current day with the following SQL but i want the data to for last 30 days with percentage of each of stage

here is my SQL

```
DECLARE @date DATE
SET @date = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())

SELECT  CASE
                    WHEN @date > X.PresentationDate AND @date < GiveAwayDate THEN 'D3'
                    WHEN @date >= DATEADD(DD, -4, X.PresentationDate) AND @date <= X.PresentationDate THEN 'D2'
                    WHEN @date < DATEADD(DD, -4, X.PresentationDate) THEN 'D1'
                    ELSE 'Unknown'
        END AS 'Stage',
        COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM(
        SELECT DISTINCT     GiveAwayDate,
                            CreatedD AS 'CreatedDate',
                            CONVERT(DATE, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Comm, 'Cancel Date: ', ''), 'th ', ' '), 'rd ', ' '), 'nd ', ' '), '1st ', '1 ')) AS 'PresentationDate'
        FROM                A_CD CD
        INNER JOIN(
                            SELECT DISTINCT
                                    Bran,
                                    Agent,
                                    Reference
                            FROM
                                    Loans
                            WHERE
                                    InsertDate = @date) A
        ON                  LEFT(CD.Bran, 1) = A.Bran
        AND                 CD.Agent = A.Agent
        AND                 CD.Reference = A.Reference
        WHERE               Comm2 = 'D1'
        AND     LTRIM(RTRIM(Done)) = ''
        AND     CreatedD              != @date
        AND     GiveAwayDate                > @date) X
GROUP BY CASE
                    WHEN @date > X.PresentationDate AND @date < GiveAwayDate THEN 'D3'
                    WHEN @date >= DATEADD(DD, -4, X.PresentationDate) AND @date <= X.PresentationDate THEN 'D2'
                    WHEN @date < DATEADD(DD, -4, X.PresentationDate) THEN 'D1'
                    ELSE 'Unknown'
        END
```

above SQL gives output like below

```
Stage   Count
D1      818
D2      839
D3      56
```

I now wanted to modify the sql so that instead of todays date it should give count for each stage for **last 30 days** with percentage.

```
Stage   Count Percentage
D1      818   47.75
D2      839   48.97
D3      56    3.38
```

I tried some bits

```
DECLARE @date DATE
DECLARE @prevDate DATE
SET @date = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
SET @prevDate = DATEADD(day,-30,@date)
    
    SELECT  CASE
                        WHEN @date > X.PresentationDate AND @date < GiveAwayDate THEN 'D3'
                        WHEN @date >= DATEADD(DD, -4, X.PresentationDate) AND @date <= X.PresentationDate THEN 'D2'
                        WHEN @date < DATEADD(DD, -4, X.PresentationDate) THEN 'D1'
                        ELSE 'Unknown'
            END AS 'Stage',
            COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
    FROM(
            SELECT DISTINCT     GiveAwayDate,
                                CreatedD AS 'CreatedDate',
                                CONVERT(DATE, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Comm, 'Cancel Date: ', ''), 'th ', ' '), 'rd ', ' '), 'nd ', ' '), '1st ', '1 ')) AS 'PresentationDate'
            FROM                A_CD CD
            INNER JOIN(
                                SELECT DISTINCT
                                        Bran,
                                        Agent,
                                        Reference
                                FROM
                                        Loans
                                WHERE
                                        InsertDate between @date AND @prevDate) A
            ON                  LEFT(CD.Bran, 1) = A.Bran
            AND                 CD.Agent = A.Agent
            AND                 CD.Reference = A.Reference
            WHERE               Comm2 = 'D1'
            AND     LTRIM(RTRIM(Done)) = ''
            AND     CreatedD              != @date
            AND     GiveAwayDate     between @date AND @prevDate) X
    GROUP BY CASE
                        WHEN @date > X.PresentationDate AND @date < GiveAwayDate THEN 'D3'
                        WHEN @date >= DATEADD(DD, -4, X.PresentationDate) AND @date <= X.PresentationDate THEN 'D2'
                        WHEN @date < DATEADD(DD, -4, X.PresentationDate) THEN 'D1'
                        ELSE 'Unknown'
            END
```

Can anybody help me in this.

Comment: why it has C# tag ?

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL, what RDBMS are you *really* using? How does C# come into this problem? I don't see any C# code in the above, so can you elaborate on why you need C# in this solution or what about the above is related to the language??

Comment: BTW ... take a look at CTE ... they are more readable than using subqueries...

Comment: i gotta say, that's a very uh. unique indentation style. I think you'd do well to add expected and source data as a text table

Comment: @siggemannennow check

Comment: @siggemannen I would say that indentation style is simply dreadful. You can't even read that code as it is.

Comment: Table definitions, sample data and desired output from the sample data would go a long way to making this question answerable.

Comment: Slight detour...be careful using `BETWEEN`, especially with datetime. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: Just a side note.   Declare @date = getdate();    The result would be today's date.

Comment: Maybe you meant: `and GiveAwayDate between @prevDate and @date) X`? From the smallest `dateAdd(dd,-30,@date)` to the largest `@date=getDate()`

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
DECLARE @date DATE;
DECLARE @prevDate DATE;
SET @date = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());
SET @prevDate = DATEADD(day,-30,@date);

WITH A AS (
    SELECT
    DISTINCT
              Bran,
              Agent,
              Reference
        FROM
              Loans
       WHERE
             InsertDate between @date AND @prevDate
)
,
X AS (
    SELECT
    DISTINCT
              GiveAwayDate,
              CreatedD AS 'CreatedDate',
              CONVERT(DATE, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Comm, 'Cancel Date: ', ''), 'th ', ' '), 'rd ', ' '), 'nd ', ' '), '1st ', '1 ')) AS 'PresentationDate'
        FROM
              A_CD  CD
              INNER JOIN A
                      ON LEFT(CD.Bran, 1) = A.Bran
                     AND CD.Agent = A.Agent
                     AND CD.Reference = A.Reference
       WHERE
              Comm2 = 'D1'
         AND  LTRIM(RTRIM(Done)) = ''
         AND  CreatedD  != @date
         AND  GiveAwayDate between @date AND @prevDate
)
,
C AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'TOTAL' FROM X
)
      SELECT
              CASE
                   WHEN @date > X.PresentationDate AND @date < GiveAwayDate THEN 'D3'
                   WHEN @date >= DATEADD(DD, -4, X.PresentationDate) AND @date <= X.PresentationDate THEN 'D2'
                   WHEN @date < DATEADD(DD, -4, X.PresentationDate) THEN 'D1'
                   ELSE 'Unknown'
              END AS 'Stage',
              COUNT(*) AS 'Count',
              ROUND( 100 * ( CONVERT( FLOAT, COUNT(*) ) / CONVERT( FLOAT, C.TOTAL ) ), 2 ) AS 'Percentage'
        FROM
              X
              CROSS JOIN C
    GROUP BY
              CASE
                   WHEN @date > X.PresentationDate AND @date < GiveAwayDate THEN 'D3'
                   WHEN @date >= DATEADD(DD, -4, X.PresentationDate) AND @date <= X.PresentationDate THEN 'D2'
                   WHEN @date < DATEADD(DD, -4, X.PresentationDate) THEN 'D1'
                   ELSE 'Unknown'
              END
;
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?